# Set variable in Angular per template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to update a variable on a per template basis.
My main index file (the layout file) displays this value. I can use ng-init, but that only works if I call ng-init before the expression.
If I use ng-init on the template pages, it does not work (I suspect due to code order).

ng-ignit

```
<div ng-init="amount='4'"></div>
```

Index.html (layout file)

```
<span class="amount">{{amount}}</span>
```

Main_controller.js

```
$scope.amount = 1; //default value
```

How can I have multiple templates with different values of the amount variable?

Comment: `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.` So [they say](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: OK -- but how do I change the value of $scope.amount when I load a different template?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a directive if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways of achieving what you desire.  But the most relevant way to what you're looking for is using a resolve.

Use a resolve in your [routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

var sampleApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/page1', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
        controller: 'myController',
        resolve: {
          data: 1
        }
      }).
      when('/showOrders', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrdersController',
        resolve: {
          data: 2
        }
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/page1'
      });
  }]);
```

In your controller

```
sampleApp.controller('myController', function($scope, data){
    $scope.amount = data;
})
```

Comment: This is not working — I get the following error: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got number
I tried returning the number like this:  resolve: {
                    data: function(){return 5}
                }
but, the number does not render. There error does go away however.

Comment: Yuh opps, you need to use a function - thats correct.  Make sure the controller you have called is listed as the controller in your routeProvider? Is this the case? If not, you need to create another service to hold your communicate data between your controllers.

Comment: hmm...In my main_controller file I have this:
var app = angular.module('Tm.controllers.Main', ['ngRoute'])
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, data) {
 $scope.amount = data;
}]);

Comment: And my app.js i have this:
  angular.module('Tm', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngAnimate',
        'mobile-angular-ui',
        'Tm.controllers.Main'
  ])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/03-added', {
                templateUrl: '03-added.html',
                reloadOnSearch: false,
                controller: 'MainController',
                resolve: {
                    data: function(){return 5}
                }
            });

});

Comment: You need to add 'data' to your dependency list  var app = angular.module('Tm.controllers.Main', ['ngRoute']) app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'data', function($scope, $http, data) {
    $scope.amount = data;
}]);

Comment: That results in this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data <- MainController